# Spring referencing a protoyype bean with ref in ProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring

This is from [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-api-proxying-intf), section 9.5.4

```
<bean id="myAdvisor" class="com.mycompany.MyAdvisor">
    <property name="someProperty" value="Custom string property value"/>
</bean>

<bean id="debugInterceptor"class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.DebugInterceptor">
</bean>

<bean id="person" 
    class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="com.mycompany.Person"/>

    <property name="target" ref="personTarget"/>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>myAdvisor</value>
            <value>debugInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now, the note below the code says:

> You might be wondering why the list
>   doesn't hold bean references. The reason for this is that if the
>   ProxyFactoryBean's singleton property is set to false, it must be able
>   to return independent proxy instances. If any of the advisors is
>   itself a prototype, an independent instance would need to be returned,
>   **so it's necessary to be able to obtain an instance of the prototype
>   from the factory; holding a reference isn't sufficient.**

Could someone please explain how this works. I know the various scopes. So I know that a new instance needs to be returned if advisors are prototype. But I did not get the last statement (highlighted in bold). If I specify `ref="debugInterceptor"` will the bean creation mechanism change? Does it mean that if I `ref` a bean, it will be a singleton instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean that if I ref a bean, it will be a singleton instance.

No, but the bean being referred to will be instantiated when the referring bean is instantiated.  If Bean A (singleton scope) has a `ref` to Bean B (prototype scope), then Bean B will be created and injected into Bean A just the once. As far as Bean A is concerned, Bean B *is* a singleton.

The `ProxyFactoryBean` must hold a list of bean names so that it doesn't force the dereferencing of the interceptors when the `ProxyFactoryBean` itself is created. By holding a list of names, it can defer the lookup of the interceptors until the last minute, allowing the interceptors to be prototype scoped beans.

Does that help?